# How to invoke azure b2c signup using MSAL in a SPA

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am looking to invoke a popup from a SPA to the Azure B2C signup page.

From one of the sample applications a login popup can be invoked, but how would I open directly to a signup page?

```
    function login() {
        clientApplication.loginPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes, "login_hint=foo@bar.com").then(function (idToken) {
            clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                updateUI();
            }, function (error) {
                clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                    updateUI();
                }, function (error) {
                    logMessage("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                });
            })
        }, function (error) {
            logMessage("Error during login:\n" + error);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found you can invoke the popup using a Signup policy instead of a Login policy and it will open the signup screen.

Set the authority with policy = signup policy name

authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/xxxxtenant.onmicrosoft.com/" + policy,

...

```
    var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, function (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
        // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
    });
```